# How to check for data and download JSON object periodically with AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have AlarmManager and need to perform work on Background, to download JSON obj. if have new data in db. Can I make instead running a service (I don't need service to running all the time, I need just to download data and that's it. But I need that periodically every 1 or more minutes.
I was thinking of using JobScheduler combining with AlarmManager but I think this is not good approach

Sometimes after some time service is killed by OS and AlarmManager not starting again.

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        // Hopefully your alarm will have a lower frequency than this!
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + INTERVAL_ONE_MINUTE,
                INTERVAL_ONE_MINUTE, alarmIntent);
        Log.d("Alarm", "Started");
    }
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class NotificationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ExampleJobService.class);
        context.startService(i);
        }
    }
```

**IntentService class**

```
public class ExampleJobService extends IntentService {
private void doBackgroundWork() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
//some work here
    }
  }
}
 private void downloadJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
//some work here
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tasks run on Android in the background, kill more than 10 seconds

To solve this problem

Use the foreground service to resolve this issue

Please read this page

[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?authuser=1)

Comment: I don't need a running service, 5-10 seconds will be enough for my work. But need to be repeatedly with `AlarmManager`. Can I instead `Service` to run the code like a `Thread` or something else. Because AlarmManager working fine, but after some time `Service` don't restarted again.

Comment: You can replace AlarmManager with WorkManager and this will help you

Comment: But WorkManager min interval is 15 minutes. I need more often like 1 or 5 minutes interval.

Comment: try JobScheduler

Comment: It's the same. min interval of 15 minutes and don't work in doze mode